# Much slower MySQL performance on virtualized server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vsphere, esxi

I'm in the process of both virtualizing and updating an old Linux server running a reporting system developed in house (Apache, MySQL, PHP).

The old physical server is running 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS, MySQL 5.1.41 and PHP 5.3. The server has an Intel Xeon CPU X3460 @ 2.80GHz (4 cores), 4GB RAM.

We have ESXI 5.5 running on an HP DL380G6 with 2 x Intel Xeon X5650 6 Core 2.66ghz and 32GB RAM.

I created a new VM with 4 cores and 4GB RAM, and did a clean install of 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, MySQL 5.7.21 and PHP 7.0, migrated our app, and everything is running much slower. I believe it's MySQL because when doing the same direct query on the old physical server vs the new virtualized one, queries can take 8 seconds (VM) instead of 1 (Physical). The tables all have appropriate indexes, running "EXPLAIN" on each server provides the same results, yet one is substantially slower. When a page is running numerous complex queries, it can take a minute+ to load instead of a few seconds.

Any idea why this can be? Same dataset, same query, same engine (MyISAM). The VM has much more recent versions of everything, same number of cores and same RAM. I even tried doubling the VM CPU to 2 sockets, 4 cores and 8GB RAM, and it doesn't seem to have a substantial impact.

I've compared the MySQL configuration and nothing is jumping out at me at being very different.

What might I be missing here? Is it the virtual host hardware?

Comment: " I believe it's MySQL" Did you properly configure MySQL?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Like I said, I've compared the config files and nothing seems out of the ordinary between the two. Though, they are different versions of Ubuntu and MySQL so I supposed there's always a chance I'm missing something in the newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade the vmware tools? if not do so. 
Then, on this ESXi host, do you have other VMs on it? If yes, I would advise you to create a resource pool and then configure the resource limits. 
In the resource pool the amount of resource you assign will be in a way reserved for your VM, so you won't have to share with other VMs.